# Getting the latest row in sql (getting one out of duplicates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database wherein I store data and once it is updated the updated data will be saved .. (have the same row data except the status and approvers)
For better understanding here is my table

```
    | RequestID   |  RequestDate  |  PartNumber  | StatusID |  FullName  |
    | 171367      |  2015-05-11   | PTA#522589   |   4      | Jfuentes   |
    | 171367      |  2015-05-11   | PTA#522589   |   5      | JReyes     |
    | 171367      |  2015-05-11   | PTA#522589   |   6      | JLabo      |
    | 171367      |  2015-05-11   | PTA#522589   |   7      | JGulbin    |
    | 171367      |  2015-05-11   | PTA#522589   |   8      | Egulbin    |
```

So everytime the the request is approved another row is added.

But then, I wanted to get only **one out the 5** which has the latest status of the RequestID ..

I tried using Distinct but there are columns that I can't include and get this error :

> The text, ntext, or image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT.

Is there any other way to get the all the columns in the row I wanted to have ?

Here's my query :

```
SELECT r.[RequestID],r.[RequestDate],r.[PARNumber],r.[StatusID],p.[DeliveryDate] 
, r.[PurchaseComment],r.[UID],p.[DeliveryDate],r.[FullName],r.[Email]          
,r.[EntityName],r.[DepartmentName],r.[DepartmentID],r.[InboxUID]
,r.[ProgramID],r.[ProgramCode],r.[ProgramName],r.[CostCenterCode]           
,p.[PartDesc],p.[SupplierID],p.[AccountType],p.[CurrName]
,p.[PartQuantity],p.[PiecePrice], p.[PartNumber], p.[DeliveryDate], p.[UnitName] 
FROM [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] r 
JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] p on p.[RequestID] = r.[RequestID]
JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[REQApproval] a on a.[RequestID] = r.[RequestID] 
JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Departments] d on d.[DepartmentID] = r.[DepartmentID]
WHERE  [EntityName]  like '%.PTA'
```

Is there any other way to get the all the columns in the row I wanted to have ?
All I needed is to query all the Requests without duplicating it on my web ..

Any help would do.

Comment: What would be your desired output here?

Comment: I just want to get one out of the duplicate records I have .. The row wherein it has the latest status ID

Comment: Then @Gordon's answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "latest" status means the most recent, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by requestid
                                     order by requestdate desc, statusid desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I am not sure, though, what your sample data has to do with your query.  You only show data for one table, but your query mentions several others.

Comment: `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'row_number' is not a recognized function name.` This is what I get

Comment: @Anaiah Gordon's query is intended to show you _how_ you would go about doing this...it is not a verbatim piece of code you can plug and chug.

Comment: @Anaiah . . . `row_number()` should be a *very* recognized function in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Ok ? but how would i get the number of rows then ?

Comment: @Anaiah . . . Your question says nothing about needing the number of rows.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a question.

Comment: Ok .. don't mind my last question .. I just want to stick on the question I posted.